# Styled ordered list multi-row alignment

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am using CSS counters to style OL.

```css
.custom-ol {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.custom-ol li {
  counter-increment: step-counter;
}
.custom-ol li::before {
  content: counter(step-counter);
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 80%;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  line-height: 26px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="custom-ol">
  <li>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</li>
  <li>Blah Blah Blah</li>
  <li>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</li>
  <li>Blah Blah</li>
</ol>
```

The styling itself works fine, however I ran into styling issue in the situation when list item is longer than the parent container width: the `li`'s second string wraps around `li::before` element rather than being on the same level as the first string.

[image]

How do I make it to act like a regular `ol` item would?

I tried to add `margin-bottom` property to `li::before` but it didn't do anything to get the correct alignment.

Comment: Try `text-indent`, maybe with a negative value. See https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-indent/

Comment: @Hexaholic it worked when applied to `.custom-ol li`. Please make it an answer so I can award you, sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply some `text-indent` to `.custom-ol li`, maybe with a negative value.

Read [this](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-indent) for examples.

Comment: This was the easiest solution out of all suggested, thank you! As for other solutions they all do the trick and will be helpful for others for sure!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to position the pseudo element absolutely, relative to the containing `li`. This will require some `margin` or `padding` on the left side of the `ol` to allow space for the pseudo element.

```css
.custom-ol {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 40px; /*Add this*/
  padding-right: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.custom-ol li {
  counter-increment: step-counter;
  line-height: 26px; /*Move line-height to here*/
  position: relative; /*Add this*/
}
.custom-ol li::before {
  content: counter(step-counter);
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 80%;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  line-height: 1em; /*Reset the line-height set on the li*/
  position: absolute; /*Add this*/
  right: 100%; /*Add this*/
  top: 0; /*Add this*/
}
```

```html
<ol class="custom-ol">
  <li>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</li>
  <li>Blah Blah Blah</li>
  <li>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</li>
  <li>Blah Blah</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your li::before is essentailly inline content, try giving it some space to sit in in the margin (or padding of the line to create a space on the li that allows the forming of a rectangular piece of text. You can make then position the ::before as you like (float, inline, absolutely positioned block etc.)

Try e.g. this:

```css
.custom-ol {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.custom-ol li {
    counter-increment: step-counter;
    margin-left: 3em; 
    position:relative;
    min-height: 1.8em;
    
}
.custom-ol li::before {
    content: counter(step-counter);
    font-size: 80%;
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 1.5em;
    height:1.5em;
    border-radius: 0.75em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left:-2.5em;  
}
```

```html
   <ol class="custom-ol">
    <li>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah </li>
    <li>Blah Blah Blah </li>
    <li>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah </li>
    <li>Blah Blah </li>
   </ol>
```

It makes the ::before a circle of 1.5em diameter, and positions it just outside of the margin create on the li itself. The li is also given a minimal height to make sure the ::before elements do not overlap or touch.